# Dynamically scoped variable in java ? (a.k.a one variable per method execution)

Tags: java, recursion, scoping

I would like to know if it's possible in java to declare a variable local to the execution of the method.

For instance, if i'm doing some recursive stuff and i want to keep various counters specific to one particular execution of the method.

I don't know the correct english expression for that...

Comment: Maybe add a pseudo-code piece with desired values/output

Comment: It's funny how you know about recursion but not local variables :p

Comment: @Kai:  Agreed.  I would make sure that you know the basics of the language before delving into recursion.

Comment: my bad, my question was completely stupid...i had a problem in my code that made me think the opposite...
thanks for the answers

Comment: @Kai: sometimes you have to deal with stuff you don't want to. :-D. I have to use Java that's my burden. Some intricacies confused me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
void method()
{
     int i = 0;  // this int is local to 'method'
}
```

Comment: that has to be the easiest 50 rep you ever scored :)

Answer (score 5):

This is how Java works by default.  For example, in the following method:

```
void recursive(int i) {
  int localI = 6;
  i-= 1;
  if (i > 0) {
    recursive(i);
  }
```

localI will stay local to the current execution of the method.

Comment: Indent your code with four spaces to have it formatted as source code. I also added a missing `}` and corrected a wrong variable name in the declaration for you.

Answer (score 1):

A normal, local variable inside a method is exactly what you mean. Those local variables are allocated on the stack. Each time you call the method, whether it's in a recursive manner or not, a new copy of the variable is created.

Answer (score -2):

I think you might be talking about `static` variables.
if you declare a static variable it will save it's value between executions of the methods.

Comment: You mean `static` local variables as in C or C++. Something like that does not exist in Java.

Comment: If you declare a static variable in the class the method is in, you can use the value between method calls. Something very useful for recursion. I'm trying to believe the person asking the question knows what a local variable is.

Comment: It seems to me that he's asking the opposite of a static member variable; he wants a 'variable local to the execution of the method', i.e. a normal, local variable.